# design patterns or best practices for private labeling .NET application?

Tags: .net, wpf, deployment, white-labelling

I hope this is not too off topic but I have searched everywhere I can think of and keep coming up empty.  We have a commercial .NET application suite that works and is mature.  Some of our partners have asked us to provide a private label version of the software for them to sell under their name.

The scope of the private labeling includes at a minimum

1. Assembly Name
2. Application Icon
3. Splash Screen
4. Application name instances within the application

I know we can use resource files for the strings within the application but what about some of the other big ticket items listed above.  The only way I know to specify these items is through the project configuration in Visual Studio.  I am looking for a repeatable process so that I can automate the building of not only our standard release but also any number of private label versions as well.

Does anyone have experience with this?  If not does anyone have any reasonable ideas on how to do this intelligently (without manually making the changes for each iteration)?